# Set HTML table cell background colour according to text content

Tags: html, css, perl, html-table

I have written a Perl program to create a web page with an HTML table derived from text file `textfile.txt`.

I would like to change it so that cells of the table are coloured according to the text content. For instance, if the text is `Reject` then background of the cell should be red.

Here are two methods that I tried. Neither of them worked

#### Method 1

```perl
if ( $_ eq "REJECT" ) {
    print map { "<td style=width:705 bgcolor=#FF0000 >REJECT</td>" } @$d;
}
```

#### Method 2

```perl
foreach my $d ( @data ) {

    $d //= '';    # Convert undefined values to empty strings

    my $class;

    if ( $d eq 'REJECT' ) {
        $class = 'hilite';
    }

    $html .= '<td';
    $html .= " class='$class'" if $class;
    $html .= ">$d</td>";
}
```

#### Perl program

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

use strict;
use warnings;

my $output = `cat textfile.txt`;
my @lines = split /\n/, $output;

my @data;

foreach my $line ( @lines ) {
    chomp $line;
    my @d = split /\s+/, $line;
    push @data, \@d;
}

my $color1 = "black";
my $color2 = "darkgreen";
my $color3 = "black";
my $color4 = "red";
my $color5 = "lime";

my $num    = 6;
my $title  = "This is the heading";
my $fstyle = "Helvetica";

print "<body bgcolor = $color3>";
print "<font color = $color5  face = $fstyle  size = $num>$title</font><br />";

foreach my $d ( @data ) {

    print "<html>";
    print "<body>";
    print "<table style=table-layout= fixed width= 705 height=110 text = $color4 border = 2 bordercolor = $color1 bgcolor = $color2>";
    print "<tr>";
    print map {"<th style=width:705 >Column1</th>"}
            print map {"<th style=width:705 >Column2</th>"}
            print "</tr>";
    print "<tr>";
    print map {"<td style=width:705 >$_</td>"} @$d;

    if ( $d eq 'REJECT' ) {
        print map {"<td style=width:705 bgcolor=#FF0000 >Reject</td>"} @$d;
    }

    print "</tr>";
    print "</table>";
    print "</body>";
    print "</html>";
}
```

Input text file:

```
Column1 Column2
Accept   Reject
Accept   Reject
Accept   Reject
```

This line

```
print map { "<td style=width:705 bgcolor=#FF0000 >Reject</td>"
```

is adding the background color RED to the cell but it is not matching the condition `Reject`.

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Why do you have `map { ... }` around the `<th>` strings? You have clearly found that something is wrong  because you have discovered that it won't work if you end the statement with a semicolon. You mustn't blindly copy other people's code without understanding what it does. What you have written will print `Column2` first followed by `Column1`.

Comment: *"This line is adding the background color RED to the cell but it is not matching the condition Reject"* What do you mean by this? All the lines contain `Reject` and all of them are displayed in red. That is what you asked for.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here. I have attached the output of the script as well. This Perl script takes the textfile.txt as an input and prints its content in an html table format as shown above. I just need to change the Reject cell in the output to RED.
That is, if the table cell value is Reject then print background of that cell to RED.
The above code is kind of POC and also I have replaced actual values with generic terms but the requirement is same. And yes I have took parts of code from web as I am very new to perl script and putting as much as effort as I could to learn.

Comment: *"yes I have took parts of code from web as I am very new to perl script and putting as much as effort as I could to learn"* Taking pieces of code from the internet is *not* putting in effort to learn. You have been using `map { ... }` for several days now without a proper reason. I say again, ***you must never*** simply copy someone else's code without understanding what it does and how it works. Given my warnings I hoped that you would at least read the Perl documentation on `map`. Go and do it now.

Comment: I don't know what improvement you think you made by removing the Perl code from your question. I've put it back.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the errors in your Perl code

- As I said, you are misusing `map`
- You are creating a new HTML document for every element of `@data`. What do you expect the browser to do with multiple `<html>` elements? It can't display them all
- You are expecting the string `REJECT` to match `Reject`
- You are using a mixture of CSS `style` strings and element attributes. For instance

  ```
  print "<table style=table-layout= fixed width= 705 height=110 text = $color4 border = 2 bordercolor = $color1 bgcolor = $color2>"
  ```

  should be

  ```
  print qq{<table
          style="table-layout:fixed; width=705; height=110; text=$color4"
          border=2
          bordercolor="$color1"
          bgcolor="$color2">\n}
  ```

  because `table-layout`, `width`, `height`, and `text` are CSS properties, while `border`, `bordercolor`, and `bgcolor` are HTML element attributes

  I think you should be writing CSS to solve this problem, but that is another matter

It would also help you a lot if you printed a newline `"\n"` after each HTML element. That way the output will be much more readable and you will be able to see better what you have created

Please don't persist with this *"try things until it works"* approach. You always end up coming here for help to get you out of the mess you've created, and you're not asking intelligent questions. To be using `map` like that after so long means you're not learning at all, and you owe it to yourself as well as your employer to learn the language properly

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that performs correctly, but it is no more than a correction of your own code. The problems that I have outlined have been fixed, and that is all

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $color1 = 'black';
my $color2 = 'darkgreen';
my $color3 = 'black';
my $color4 = 'red';
my $color5 = 'lime';

my $size   = 6;
my $title  = 'This is the heading';
my $fstyle = 'Helvetica';

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

print "<body bgcolor = $color3>\n";
print "<font color = $color5 face=$fstyle size=$size>$title</font><br />\n";

{
    print "<html>\n";
    print "<body>\n";

    print qq{<table
            style="table-layout:fixed; width=705; height=110; text=$color4"
            border=2
            bordercolor="$color1"
            bgcolor="$color2">\n};

    print "<tr>\n";
    print qq{<th style="width:705" >Column1</th>};
    print qq{<th style="width:705" >Column2</th>};
    print "</tr>\n";

    open my $fh, '<', 'textfile.txt' or die $!;

    while ( <$fh> ) {

        my @line = split;

        print "<tr>\n";

        for ( @line ) {

            if ( /reject/i ) {
                print qq{<td style=width:705 bgcolor=red>$_</td>};
            }
            else {
                print "<td style=width:705>$_</td>"
            }
        }

        print "</tr>\n";
    }

    print "</table>\n";
    print "</body>\n";
    print "</html>\n";
}
```

#### output

```html
Content-type: text/html

<body bgcolor = black>
<font color = lime face=Helvetica size=6>This is the heading</font><br />
<html>
<body>
<table
        style="table-layout:fixed; width=705; height=110; text=red"
        border=2
        bordercolor="black"
        bgcolor="darkgreen">
<tr>
<th style="width:705" >Column1</th><th style="width:705" >Column2</th></tr>
<tr>
<td style=width:705>Column1</td><td style=width:705>Column2</td></tr>
<tr>
<td style=width:705>Accept</td><td style=width:705 bgcolor=red>Reject</td></tr>
<tr>
<td style=width:705>Accept</td><td style=width:705 bgcolor=red>Reject</td></tr>
<tr>
<td style=width:705>Accept</td><td style=width:705 bgcolor=red>Reject</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Appearance

[image: This is the result]

I still have misgivings about your approach. Hacking together a program from bits and pieces of others' work that you don't understand is a recipe for failure. If you have no inclination to explore and learn the details enough to survive on your own then you have chosen the wrong job

- I think you should be using a template system such as
  [`Template::Toolkit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Toolkit) instead of printing `HTML` from your Perl program
- The colours should be changed using CSS and an appropriate `class`, rather than printing HTML attributes in line

You seem to think that a casual and approximate approach is fine, or at least that you are unwilling to offer any more, but while that may be true of other professions, software engineering requires much more care and precision